# Bundle.put(String, Pacelable) vs. Intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Can anybody explain why Bundle.put wont except android.os.Uri (implements Parcelabe, Comparable) but Intent.putExtra will?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("some string");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", uri); //this is ok...builds, runs, works

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("key", uri); //wont build
```

I'm trying to give each fragment I make a uri reference to the content that populates it through the Fragment arguments. It's not a big deal, because I pass it as a string and re-parse it in the Fragment, but it would be nice to avoid this step.

EDITED:
The above code now works.

Comment: did you at least check the Bundle class documentation if it has a method `put(...)`? is there a "Intelligent code completion" not working in your IDE ?

Comment: I actually had both the documents open at the time I was typing the question. I forgot to include "Parcelable" with put. I accepted the answer below. It was the first thing I tried. I cant begin to explain why, but I really did have Android Studio refusing to build with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Selvin, there is no `put()` method on [the `Bundle` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). `Uri` implements `Parcelable`; to put a `Uri` in a `Bundle`, [call `putParcelable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29).